# Why can I not convert this to button based of an xml Id?

Tags: java, android, xml

This part is for setting the ids for some buttons that I have created.

```
 protected void btnClicked(View view){
        Button btnSelected = (Button)view;

        switch (btnSelected.getId()){

            case R.id.btn1:
                btnId = 1;
                break;
            case R.id.btn2:
                btnId = 2;
                break;
            case R.id.btn3:
                btnId = 3;
                break;
            case R.id.btn4:
                btnId = 4;
                break;
            case R.id.btn5:
                btnId = 5;
                break;
            case R.id.btn6:
                btnId = 6;
                break;
            case R.id.btn7:
                btnId = 7;
                break;
            case R.id.btn8:
                btnId = 8;
                break;
            case R.id.btn9:
                btnId = 9;
                break;
            }
```

**THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM OCCURS**

I can't let the button "btnSelectForRobot" to be an id of an XML tag if it's meeting the 'case' condition. It tells me an error,

Error:(168, 45) error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Button

What should I do in order to make it work?

```
protected  void robotPlayerAuto(){

         //Checking for empty buttons so that the robot can play.
          for(int btnIds =0; btnIds < 9; btnIds++){
              if(!(player1.contains(btnIds) || player2.contains(btnIds))){
                  robotPlayer.add(btnIds);
              }
          }

            Random randomBtnPicker = new Random();
            int pickedRandom =  randomBtnPicker.nextInt(robotPlayer.size()-0)+0;
            int btnIdRobot = robotPlayer.get(pickedRandom);
            Button btnSelectForRobot = null;


            switch (btnIdRobot){
                case 1:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn6;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn7;
                    break;
                case 8:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn8;
                    break;
                case 9:
                    btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn9;
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you need to get a view `Button`

```
btnSelectForRobot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
btnSelectForRobot.setId(R.id.btn1);
```

instead of

```
btnSelectForRobot = R.id.btn1;
```

something like this:

```
    switch (btnIdRobot){
        case 1:
            btnSelectForRobot.setId(R.id.btn1);
            break;
        case 2:
            btnSelectForRobot.setId(R.id.btn2);
            break;
```

comment downbelow if you still need help

Comment: It works as well! thank you so much

Comment: so why you mark Alex's answer Correct instead of mine? misclick?
 :D @newprogrammer